# How to secure a WCF Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, security

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS. I have another website hosted in asp.net mvc. It is a public web site. I want to secure my WCF service so that it won't be accessible from any applications other than my MVC application, or which I give access.

Can I do this using forms authentication?

**Update:**

I had gone through several examples, but I couldn't get an effective one. I dont want to use ssl. Login feature is not there in my web spplication. If required, a programitic login can be implemented. All I need is, deny access if the service is not called from my website. I've done this in web service using forms authentication. But here, the httpcontext is null.

Comment: FYI, the term is "a WCF Service", not "a WCF".

Comment: There are many potential duplicates to your question; for now it is too broad. [Research the security settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732362.aspx) relevant to your bindings, and update your question when you have trouble understanding or implementing a specific principle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. WCF calls go through the same pipeline so that if you check for specific principals (usernames or roles), your checks will fail/succeed depending on the Forms cookie.

More details in my blog entry

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/04/aspnet-forms-authentication-sharing-for.html

where I show how to share the forms identity between a web app and hosted silverlight app which calls WCF services.

In case of yet another type of the client application, the way you get the cookie value at the client side can vary. Silverlight just inherits cookies from the web application it is run from.

Assuming your client is a console application, you could even expose an unguarded method from the WCF service which accepts loginname+password and returns the cookie to the client. This way, the console application would first call this unguarded method to login the user and then, using returned cookie, would call other WCF services guarded with forms authentication.